# Switch on and off a lamp using relay

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to switch a house lamp on and off using **Raspberry Pi 3 and a 5V relay**.

I'm able to switch it on and off using python code, but I'm not into python, **i want to use node and js**.  Been trying for a week to find a node example for doing this, but nothing works. This should be pretty simple for someone with more experience.

**This is my setup:**
[image: pi_gpio]

Comment: have any answers worked for you? If you can't upvote, do leave a comment suggesting your success. This will help others later on in time

Answer (score 0):

There are many Node.js libraries to control GPIO. I'd recommend [rpi-gpio](https://github.com/JamesBarwell/rpi-gpio.js). After npm-installing it, you can control the GPIO21 with something along these lines (untested code):

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio')
var gpiop = gpio.promise;

gpiop.setup(21, gpio.DIR_OUT)
    .then(() => {
        return gpiop.write(21, true); // ON
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error: ', err.toString());
    })
```

You can find other alternatives such as https://github.com/jperkin/node-rpio or https://github.com/jperkin/node-rpio in the npm registry.

Comment: There is no error, but nothing is happening. Tried `gpio.DIR_HIGH`, `gpio.DIR_LOW`, same thing.
I have been trying the `onoff`  module with some progress, but it's not working as i was hoping ..by far. Here is the link: https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/issues/102